# Why can I use any letter before => in lambda expression, how it would translate to standard syntax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda

I have tried tp understand lambda expressions for a long time(many attempts).

Inside Razor view I have a `foreach` loop over the `ICollection<Comment> Comments` where `Model` is of class `Product`.

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments) {
            <p> @Html.DisplayFor(m => comment.TimeStamp)</p>
}
```

I don't understand why I can use any letter before `=>` inside that expression and it still works. If that does not matter why do I have to write anything before `=>`?

How it would translate(if it was possible) to the standard method syntax?

Comment: It works exactly the same way method parameter names work - they can be pretty much anything. The difference is for lambda expression it cannot collide with any variable already existing in the scope it's declared in.

Answer (score 2):

In your example, `m` is the parameter to your function, which is used to pass the value of `comment` in to your function. However, with the lambda, you still have access to `comment`, which you are using directly. Just because you do not use the parameter doesn't mean you can do away with it though.

As a result, you could rewrite your code snippet as:

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments) {
        <p> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TimeStamp)</p>
}
```

Comment: Ok, so does `comment == m` or `comment.Equals(m)`?

Comment: @fashiooihioh, Unless the `Comment` class does something odd, then the answer is "both". `m` and `comment` contain the same reference to a `Comment` instance.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder, I'm not familiar with `@Html.DisplayFor` specifically, but if what you say is true, my answer is wrong as I state `m` cannot be done away with, whereas you are suggesting there's an overload that takes a parameterless delegate.

Comment: @DavidArno: Yeah, that comment was misleading. I was speaking of the general case of lambdas, but of course the lambda you pass has to conform to one of the signatures what you're passing it *into* supports. I'm also not familiar with `@Html.DisplayFor`, but it [seems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee407390(v=vs.118).aspx) to require at least one argument.

Answer (score 1):

It important to understand that lambda is in its essence anonymous function declaration.

1) *I don't understand why I can use any letter before => inside that expression and it still works*

`m` is just parameter name. You can write `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.TimeStamp)` or `@Html.DisplayFor(i => i.TimeStamp)` and it would be (in this case! - see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123898/lambda-capture-problem-with-iterators)) functionally equal to your code (but more efficient)

Reason why your code works is because `m` parameter is not used in any way and code inside lambda (which is effectively function body) is using variable declared outside the function (code after `=>`). This is called [closure\captured variable](http://geekswithblogs.net/rajeevr/archive/2012/02/26/closures-and-captured-variable.aspx) - it's less efficient, have many pitfalls but can be extremely useful...

2) *If that does not matter why do I have to write anything before =>?*

Because `@Html.DisplayFor` method is declared to take `Func<TModel, TValue>` parameter which you can read as 'function which takes one argument (model) and returns single value'

3) Using normal (anonymous) method syntax:

```
@foreach (var comment in Model.Comments) {
            <p> @Html.DisplayFor(delegate(CommentsType c) { return c.TimeStamp; })</p>
}
```

....where `CommentsType` is type of `Model.Comments` property